# Setting NSFetchRequest resultType in the model editor has no effect

Tags: xcode, cocoa, core-data

I just ran into an issue with fetch request templates created via the model editor in Xcode 4.6.2. I tried to change the *Result Type* setting in the Core Data inspector of a fetch request as in this picture:

[image: fetch request details]

However, the settings are not reflected when I load the template in code:

```
NSFetchRequest *req = [self.managedObjectModel fetchRequestTemplateForName:@"itemIds"];
NSLog(@"Result type is %d", req.resultType);
```

returns **0**, a.k.a `NSManagedObjectResultType`. Likewise, the other settings under *Advanced* don't seem to be loaded from the model when I get the template. I tried both `fetchRequestTemplateForName:` and `fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:substitutionVariables:` but neither of them give the desired result. Is this a bug in Xcode/`NSManagedObjectModel` or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the managed object model compiler that comes with Xcode. It seems that in the right panel, only "Name" and "Entity" have any effect at all. What you're doing is correct, but the tool is broken.

The closest workaround is to change the result type in code. You can't modify the fetch request that you get from the model, but `NSFetchRequest` conforms to `NSCopying`, so you could make a copy and modify that. That kind of sucks but it looks like the best option with the current tools.

Comment: I filed a bug, it's also available on [OpenRadar](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=3009404).

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep the question open for a while longer in case anyone else wants to chime in. In the meantime, I'll post a radar, too.